# How do I keep from having to pass around IConfiguration and IHostingEnvironment

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-2.0

I am looking at refactoring and abstracting some code for learning purposes.

I have created this class:

```
using System;

namespace app.Classes
{
    public class Emailer : ISender
    {

        public Emailer(IConfiguration config, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
        }
    ...
}
```

Then I have another class I would like to use that class:

```
namespace app.Notifications
{
    public class PasswordReset : INotification
    {
        Emailer emailer = new Emailer();

        public PasswordReset()
        {
        }
    ...
}
```

Since the IConfiguration and IHostingEnvironment are using DI, how do I keep from having to pass them through when I instantiate a new Emailer inside PasswordReset?

Comment: Don't create a new Emailer. Pass it (or ISender) as a parameter to PasswordReset and let the DI create it for you

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: To solve the problem with your current solution, you could add a 2nd constructor to the Emailer class that instances new config and host implementations.

Comment: @SimplyGed If I go that route, then when I say new PasswordReset(), I have to pass an instance of Emailer then right ie. new PasswordReset(instanceOfEmailer).  I feel like emailer shouldn't be a concern of the controller that is calling new PasswordReset()?

Comment: You should try not to use `new` at all. If you have DI then let it create everything for you. Where do you need to create the PasswordReset class? The DI should have a provider that it uses to create the classes you have registered with it. You can pass that provider class around and use that to create the PasswordReset and it's dependencies. Take a look at this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#designing-services-for-dependency-injection) on the DotNetCore DI

Comment: If you're going to use DI, you need to use DI *all the way*. Simple as that. Inject everything and let the DI container handle the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `PasswordReset` create a new instance of `Emailer`, you should leverage the existing DI and turn `Emailer` into a Service.

Inside the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs`, add a reference to your `Emailer` class:

```
services.AddScoped<ISender, Emailer >();
```

Then change `PasswordReset` to reference your new `ISender` service:

```
namespace app.Notifications
{
    public class PasswordReset : INotification
    {
        private ISender _emailer;

        public PasswordReset(ISender emailer)
        {
            _emailer = emailer;
        }
    ...
}
```

Now you no longer need to worry about passing anything around, DI is handling it for you.

Comment: So, then how do I handling a new PasswordReset (let's say in web api controller)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question but generally, if you're creating an instance of a complex class (i.e. using the `new` keyword against something other than a struct or type), more than likely not you should be using that class in a Service.